# Integral of $\int \frac{1+\sin(2x)}{\operatorname{tg}(2x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find the $F(x)$ of this function but I don't find how to do it, I need some hints about the solution.

I know that $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ its help me? It's good way to set $2x$ as $t$?
$$\int \frac{1+\sin(2x)}{\operatorname{tg}(2x)}dx$$

**EDIT**

Its right to do it like that? 
$$\int \frac{1+2\sin(x)\cos(x)dx}{\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}}$$
$$\int \left(\frac{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}+\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)\right)dx = \int \left(\operatorname{ctg}(2x)+\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}-\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\right)dx$$ and the integral of $\displaystyle \operatorname{ctg}(2x) = \frac{\ln|\sin(2x)|}{2}+C$ and the two other is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(2x)}{2}+C$
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effective hint:

> Let $\int R(\sin x,\cos x)dx$ wherein $R$ is a rational function respect to $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. If $$R(-\sin x, -\cos x)\equiv R(\sin x, \cos x) $$ then $t=\tan x, t=\cot x$ is a good substitution.

Comment: Effective indeed! +1

Comment: its $tan(x)$ because the original substitution is $tan(\frac{x}{2})$?

Comment: @OfirAttia: Maybe. But this substitution works fast.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Set $y={\rm tg} x$ and express all the functions through $y$.

Comment: @Babak S. Thank you, my friend!

Comment: I will be so thankful if you have time and take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/406425/8581). If you have any suggestion, please let me know them. Thanks a bunch. :-)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\tan(x)=  \dfrac {\sin x}{\cos x}$$

$$I=\int \cot 2x . dx +\int \cos 2x.dx
$$